# What is the difference between IDispatch and IUnkown in COM?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, com-interface

I have read and saw example for **COM**, but I couldn't clearly get there **Interface** difference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should at least show what you have tried to get an answer by yourself.

Comment: You should also read the documentation, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

**IUnknown**  is the primal COM interface.  It provides the basic ability to "cast" a instance of a COM object to any of it's supported interfaces (QueryInterface).

**IDispatch**  builds on IUnknown adding the facility to discover at run-time the attributes and interfaces supported by the specified COM object.  This allows for late-binding and dynamic-binding.  A remedial reflection of sorts. With IDispatch, an application can discover the capability of components and invoke discovered methods (which was simplistically called automation).

See [Implementing the IDispatch Interface [Automation]](https://web.archive.org/web/20171008221327/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221037.aspx) on MSDN (resurrected from WayBack Machine - [current online version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e171f7f-0022-4e9b-ac8e-98192828e945(vs.85))).

Comment: The MSDN link is broken.

Comment: @RAM - Fixed the hyperlink issue.

Answer (score 3):

**IUnkown** is the basic interface for all COM interfaces.

**IDispatch** exposes an interfacea for objects, methods and properties to programming tools and other applications that support Automation.

Answer (score 0):

The IDispatch interface inherits from the IUnknown interface.
Please have a look at the below link.

[IDispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[IUnknown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx)